# Can't loop over array; each item works individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

The following piece of code works as expected:

```
var slctr = "What's new";
var section = document.querySelector('[aria-label="'+slctr +'"]');
var sectionAs = section.querySelectorAll('a');
$(sectionAs).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(e.target).text();
    var sectionTitle = section.getAttribute('aria-label');
    alert('Title: ' + sectionTitle+', text: ' + t);
    return false;
});
```

If I try to apply this to every `{{section}}`, the working stops:

```
var sections = [
    "What's new",
    "What's newish",
    "What's not new at all"
    ];

for(var l = 0; l < sections.length; l++){
    var slctr = sections[i];
    var section = document.querySelector('[aria-label="'+slctr +'"]');
    var sectionAs = section.querySelectorAll('a');
    $(sectionAs).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var t = $(e.target).text();
        var sectionTitle = section.getAttribute('aria-label');
        alert('Title: ' + sectionTitle + ', text: ' + t);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Why does it not work for the loop?

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: You gotta use closures... By the time the loop finishes, the value of `i` is not the same.

Comment: um `l` and `i`.

Comment: Why are you mixing DOM and jQuery to select elements? There is really no reason you even need to loop up each element.....

Comment: @epascarello - thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I am not qualified to answer the "why" in your question. I am just doing it the only way I can think of. Can you recommend anything better?

Comment: The sooner you get the list of jQuery methods in your head the better. Start with the basic `$(selector)` instead of `querySelectorAll()`, and `attr()` instead of `getAttribute()`.

Comment: @isherwood - thanks. I am aiming to avoid jQuery wherever possible. I am using it here out of despair. One day I'll rewrite it in pure JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use closures or IIFEs as you are setting some event handlers, which are some times asynchronous. You just need to update your code like:

```js
var sections = [
  "What's new",
  "What's newish",
  "What's not new at all"
];

for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    var slctr = sections[i];
    var section = document.querySelector('[aria-label="' + slctr + '"]');
    var sectionAs = section.querySelectorAll('a');
    $(sectionAs).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var t = $(e.target).text();
      var sectionTitle = section.getAttribute('aria-label');
      alert('Title: ' + sectionTitle + ', text: ' + t);
      return false;
    });
  })(i);
}
```

And one more thing is that you have used `i` for index and `l` for loop.

Comment: Thank you Praveen. I am not allowed to upvote your comment, sorry.

Comment: @RomanK Thanks man... That's alright. I voted your question up. Enjoy! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You use `l` as loop variable but then trying to access sections[i] and `i` is not defined

```
var slctr = sections[l];
```

Comment: Thank you. This was embarrassing.